# Calculating the speed a variable increases (python)

Tags: python, math, encoder, acceleration

I have a small problem that I really cant figure out how to solve after some time googling.
My project consists of a rasberry pi and a rotary encoder that I will use as a sensor to see how fast a shaft is spinning. This is then coded in Python. My problem then is that I have no clue how to calculate this. The rotary encoder is connected directly to the shaft and will spin at the same speed as the shaft, and if I use [this code](https://github.com/modmypi/Rotary-Encoder/blob/master/rotary_encoder.py) the variable "counter" will increment with 1 per "click". Assuming thats what I have to go on, I need to know how I can calculate how fast counter increases so I can get the speed of the shaft. This is because the shaft will be spinning at diffrent speeds at all times.
The reason I need to know how fast the shaft is spinning is because I have a UI that will display the speed.

I would also appreciate if you have any other approuches that I have missed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would calculate the speed :

first add this at the top
`import time`

then a start time variable

```
clk = 17
dt = 18
starttime = time.time() ## used to calculate a duration
```

if you subtract starttime from time.time() you will get how long it has been since you defined the start time variable
( time.time() - starttime )

therefore you then add this

```
if dtState != clkState:
    counter += 1
    timetakentospinshaft = time.time() - starttime ## this is how long the shaft took to spin 360 degrees
    starttime = time.time() # resetting the duartion
```

now you have the time taken, so you can calculate the speed by dividing the distance by the time
( speed = distance / time )

the distance can be calculated by multiplying the length of the shaft by 2π (calculation for circumference)
( distance = length of shaft * 2π )

Comment: But when you write starttime = time.time(), wount starttime be equal to time.time() at all times? thus, timetakentospinshaft =  0? as my username describes, I am abit out of my comfort zone heheh.

Comment: @CPlusPlusandHTMLguy the time.time() function returns the time since epoch - basically the time since the time module started recording the time, it is constantly changing because the real time is always changing

Comment: I understand that, but wount starttime be the same as time.time as they are globally defined to be equal?

Comment: @CPlusPlusandHTMLguy when you call time.time(), it returns the current time as a float. For example if the time since epoch was 2, calling time.time() would return the float '2', and when time since epoch was 3, time.time() would return the float '3', if you stored that 2 as a variable then it wouldn't change to 3

Comment: Sorry for being such noob, figured out that the reason why I thougt the starttime would be the same as time.time is because the last time i assigned an variable to be equal to another variable or etc. I did it inside an loop which constantly kept them the same.. however, I'm testing your suggesting now to see if I can make it work. I dont have my equipment here at the moment so I am using a keystroke to imitate the counter. works completly okay, only need to connect it to the ui.